# How can I take backup of specific data from single/multiple tables fin PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

Let us consider a table my_table in my_db. Here I want to backup the schema of table and data for certain period. e.g from 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-31. How can I do this? or Does Postgres allows to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use COPY Command

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE clause ) TO '/tmp/myfile.tsv'

COPY mytable FROM 'myfile.tsv'
```

Please refer https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-copy.html